# IIS Url Rewriter: Redirect language codes

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I made a web site for a client in different languages, the Urls looked like

```
https://www.example.com/en-US/Something/More
https://www.example.com/de-DE/Etwas/Mehr
https://www.example.com/fr-FR/Quelquechose/plus
```

etc.

The problem is: the client wants the language codes like /en/, /de/ and /fr/ now. No problem to change, but the pages were listed on Google quite well and lead to 404 pages now.

The site is running on IIS, it is an ASP.Net application.

Can anyone please tell me how to define a rewrite (redirect) rule to include in the web.config file that redirects all Urls like

```
http(s)://www.example.com/en-US[/...]
```

to

```
http(s)://www.example.com/en[/...]
```

I tried differnet things, but nothing worked for me. Problem is I am not good in regular expressions, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either create 3 rules that look like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectEnglish" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="en-US(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="en{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Or try something more fancy like

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectEnglish" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(en|de|fr)-[A-Za-z]{2}(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}{R:2}" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You'll probably need to tweak that second one and its worth learning a bit about regular expressions.  Find an online regex tester and try some values and make sure the stuff that you want is matching.

Comment: Thanks, that is working. Only one question: Why is the redirection type temporary and not permanent?

Comment: Great question.  Feel free to change it (do it in the UI to make it easy on yourself).  I ALWAYS post samples and do my testing with "Temporary".  If you do permanent, the browser will cache it and you'll have to clear any cache that has hit your webserver.   So basically make sure your rule is how you want it before changing it to permanent.